# Loco Translate not shows all translations

Tags: php, woocommerce, translation, cart, checkout

I am using Loco Translate to translate wordpress and woocommerce. Great plugin, but unfortunately some string translations are not visible/working on the frontend at the checkout page and cart. Could this be a child team problem?

Strings are know in Loco Translate and correctly translated, they are only not showing up at frontend.

Translation String issues:

- Have a coupon? Click here to enter your code.
- Flat rate:
- Subscribe to our newsletter

Site www.narwal.shop/checkout

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Force WP to load the language file from `languages/loco/themes/..` directory, like this inside `functions.php`:

```
add_action ( 'wp', 'load_translations' );
function load_translations() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'theme-name-here' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to wp-content and uploads directory. create a new directory and name it as same as the plugin name. then create a new directory and name it languages.
now upload your .po and .mo files in it.
the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: you should contact the creator of the (child) theme.

Every single component that displays text (i.e.: almost all of them), including themes and plugins, need to have included multilingual support for it to work.
Woocommerce does it, but you might have other components that do not. If you have a custom theme, that would be the first thing I'd check.

Unfortunately, if this is the case there is nothing you can do about it other than not use it, accept that that part of the site will not be translated or ask the developer who made them to put in the extra work to add multilingual support.

See also: https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/child-themes

Comment: Dear Rad80. Thanks for your feedback. I edited the posts, I added the specific strings. All strings are standard and translations worked before on an other webshop.

Comment: It is hard (not too say impossible) to debug this, especially given that there is an unknown child theme we do not have the source code for. You should ask this to the theme creator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a wordpress language problem. I resolved this by changing it from English to my target translation language. To achive this in your wordpress panel go to: `Settings -> General -> find language and change it`.